# docker : how to get beautiful links to containers?

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, port

I have multiple physical machines with proxmox -> ubuntu -> docker. I also have bind DNS in my network. could you please help me and tell how should I start configuring dockers (I use docker-compose) so all my services with webgui would be served at port :80 and I would have beautiful links to them ?
e.g. I do not want to remember that nodered is on port 1180, HomeAssitstant on 8123 but I would like to access them like node-red.home, HomeAssitstant.home etc.

Comment: You need to create virtual host file to point out to the docker-container:port. Which web server are you using, nginx or apache?

Comment: I do not mean to write/creat my own dockers only use official images. Then, e.g. on my Ubuntu I would like to have :
- gitlab
- artifactory
and while my ubuntu has 192.168.1.10 I would like to access gitlab webgui at 192.168.1.11(:80) and artifactory 192.168.1.12(:80) so I can bind those ip adresses in dns to gitlab.home, artifactory.home